# Euler class of quotient bundle of real projective space

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let $\gamma$ be the real tautological line bundle over the real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^n$, $V$ be the trivial bundle of rank $n+1$, and $Q$ be the quotient bundle $V/\gamma$. What is the Euler class $e(Q)$ of the quotient bundle? Thanks a lot! (I think the polynomial is either $\frac{1}{1-st}$, where $s \in H^1(\mathbb{R}P)$ is a generator, or the class is $(1-s)^{n+1}$.)

Comment: Hint: Show that the result is the tangent bundle of the projective space. Then use the fact that the Euler class is multiplicative under covering maps.